# Setting startdate on line chart

Tags: c#, datetime, charts

I am trying to figure out how to my start the X axis in my line chart at the first date in stored in an object. I have been trying for quite some time now, and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

It simply says that I can't convert from DateTime to Double, which makes sense, but I have no clue how to get around this.

I have indented the part of the code I am trying to make work. Thanks in advance!

[image]

```
private void loadChart(List<Temperatur> templist)
{
   // clear charts
   this.chart1.Series.Clear();
   this.chart2.Series.Clear();

   // add Data to charts
   Series series = this.chart1.Series.Add((templist.ElementAt(0).Date).ToString());
   Series series2 = this.chart2.Series.Add((templist.ElementAt(0).Date).ToString());
   // defines type of chart
   series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
   series2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
   // sets line thickness
   series.BorderWidth = 3;
   series2.BorderWidth = 3;
   // sets chart limits  and intervals
   chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 42;
   chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 35;
   chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 0.5;

   //sets X axis labels
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = Convert.ToDouble(templist.ElementAt(0).Date);

   // removes legend from chart
   chart1.Legends[0].Enabled = false;
   chart2.Legends[0].Enabled = false;

   foreach (Temperatur tempObj in templist)
   {
     // Add point.
     series.Points.Add(Convert.ToDouble(tempObj.Temp));

   }


   foreach (Temperatur tempObj in templist)
   {
       // Add point.
       series2.Points.Add(Convert.ToInt32(tempObj.Puls.ToString()));
   }


}
```

Comment: Please describe how it is ' not working ' - You could use AddXY to include the X-Values in your DataPoints.

Comment: Added small description of the problem.

Comment: OK, which line? The Add calls? See my comment above!

Comment: I just now saw that I had a very vague description of my problem... I want the x axis to show the dates, not the values on the chart itself.

Comment: I thought so. Use the AddXY format, which lets you include the X-Values as double s and one (or more, but you only need (one) Y-Value.

Comment: Not sure if I follow you, I don't want to add a point to the chart. Which is what I understand from the AddXY, I wan't the "timeline" to start from the date - Added picture to post for clarity. If I misunderstand, please correct me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73525/discussion-between-taw-and-matt-baech).

Comment: @TaW I was wondering if you would have time to help again, with kind of some problem, so figured a new thread wouldn't be worth it

Comment: Well, let's see. Unfortunately the old Chatroom is frozen..

Comment: yes, I have added a question over at [/r/LearnProgramming](http://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/33c5fu/need_help_with_an_error/), maybe you could look at it quick

Comment: @TaW just making sure you saw my comment, not sure how the notification system works :)

Comment: I did but I'm a bit tied up atm..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `DataPoints` in several formats.

You want them to have a X-Value of type `DateTime` and an Y-Value of type `double`, so use a call like this:

```
series.Points.AddXY(tempObj.Date, tempObj.Temp);
```

If you want to start the display at a `Minimum` you need to use the key of the Points collection, if the X-Values are dates it will be a date, if they are numbers (doubles by default) you use a number.

If you never have set the X-Values they will start at `0` by default (which will be shown as `1899` when cast to a DateTime..)

Doing so is a little tricky, as the `Minimum` only accepts doubles; that's because even when your type is set to `DateTime` and even though you have added `DateTime` X-Values, **internally** they still are stored as `double`.

To set the `Minimum` etc after you have added the `DataPoints` with their `X-Values` as `DateTimes` you can use :

```
int yourStartIndex = 1;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = series.Points.ElementAt(yourStartIndex).XValue;
```

To control the displayed X-Axis label set its `Format`; here is an example:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "dd.MM.\\'yy hh\\h";
```

Note the added 'h' and the added apostrophe resulting in something like: `21.03'15 12h`

Comment: With a slight chance of being rude. Is there any chance you could join the chatroom again?